# Come si esprime in italiano "undesirable effects" di una cura, terapia o medicazione?

Tags: translation, phrase-request

Le diverse cure, terapie o medicazioni producono sull'organismo quello che in inglese si chiama "undesirable effects", in catalano "efectes no desitjats" e in castigliano "efectos indeseados". Come posso esprimere questo concetto in italiano?

Su [WordReference](https://www.wordreference.com/enit/undesirable) ho trovato questo esempio

> Il farmaco può provocare effetti indesiderati, come la sonnolenza

ma appare anche "indesiderabile" e, se scrivo su Google "effetto medicina", "effetto medicinale", "effetto indesiderato farmaco", ecc. si trovano altre espressioni diverse, per cui non riesco a capacitarmi di quali siano quelle che si usano.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

L’espressione che cerchi è *effetti [collaterali](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/collaterale/)*:

> c. fig. Che si fa, o avviene, o si sviluppa insieme con altro,
> parallelamente ad altro, come fatto o fenomeno concomitante e, spesso,
> secondario: *manifestazioni, effetti collaterali.* In partic., nel
> linguaggio medico, ***effetti c.,*** gli effetti di un trattamento su organi
> o funzioni dell’organismo che non sono utili alla cura della malattia
> per la quale esso è stato prescritto, e possono anche essere (oltre
> che indifferenti) nocivi o comunque indesiderati;

Talvolta sui bugiardini dei medicinali in effetti si trova anche l’espressione *effetti indesiderati*, che hai trovato tu.